# PHP what is wrong with this class construction?

Tags: php

I am trying to upgrade a php file to version 8.0, but am getting error calls at this class:

```
class dbgate{
    var $connection;
    var $logConn;
    var $error;
    var $errorNo;
    var $insertId;
    var $result;
    var $stmt;
    
    function dbgate($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name)
    {       
        $this->connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);
    }

    function connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name){      
        
        $this->connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
        
        if ($this->connection->connect_error) trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $this->connection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    function format($value, $notagstrip=false){
        // escapes value for query
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $value = stripslashes($value);
        
        if($notagstrip==false) $value = strip_tags($value); 
        //die(var_dump($value));
        $value = $this->connection->escape_string(trim($value));
        return $value;
    }
    function selectDb($dbname){
        if(!$this->connection->select_db($dbname)) trigger_error('Database selection failed: Cannot Connect to '.$dbname);
    }

    function select($sql){ 
        // returns result set
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->result = $this->connection->query($this->sql);
        $this->error = $this->connection->error;
        $this->errorNo = $this->connection->errno;
        //$this->logQuery();
        if(!$this->result) {return false;}
        elseif($this->result->num_rows < 1) return false;
        return $this->result;
    } 
    function getarray($res,$type = 'BOTH'){
        if($res == '') $res = $this->result;
        return $res->fetch_array(constant('MYSQLI_'.$type));        
    }
    function num_rows($sql){ 
        // returns result set
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->result = $this->connection->query($this->sql);
        //$this->logQuery();
        if(!$this->result) return false;    
        return $this->result->num_rows;
    } 

}
```

The error given suggests that there is something wrong with the function "select".

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\emp\includes\dbmysqli.php:125 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\emp\conn.php(44): dbgate->select('SELECT * FROM t...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\emp\index.php(7): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\emp\includes\dbmysqli.php on line 125

Can anyone help me decode this?

Comment: This function `dbgate()` should be `__construct()` for years now. So most likely your class never actually makes the connection to the database

Comment: `Prior to PHP 8.0.0, classes in the global namespace will interpret a method named the same as the class as an old-style constructor. That syntax is deprecated, and will result in an E_DEPRECATED error but still call that function as a constructor. If both __construct() and a same-name method are defined, __construct() will be called.

In namespaced classes, or any class as of PHP 8.0.0, a method named the same as the class never has any special meaning.` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Also functions like `get_magic_quotes_gpc` are removed now